# Why is flex div 100% width of parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am confused as to why a flex div takes up 100% width of its parent element. Take the following snippet:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#flex {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="flex">
     <div>Item</div>
     <div>Item</div>
     <div>Item</div>
     <div>Item</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why is the flex div expanding to 100% width of the parent? Is there a way to make the flex div only as wide as the contents within it?

Any help appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: "display: flex;" property nature is to cover 100% width just like "display: block;" property. If you don't want to cover whole area then you can use "display: inline-flex" or "display: inline".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `#flex` div has `display: flex` applied. That's a block-level command (such as `display: block`) which, [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276), occupies the full width of the parent. Use `display: inline-flex` instead.